# Addthis Bug on Hover

Tags: html, css, addthis

I downloaded this plugin called addthis : https://www.addthis.com/ and I installed it on my website. The problem is here, when I hover over a button, it moves to a side. This is not normal, and the only style I am giving it is for the layout and not any hover styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in your style.css

```
a:hover
{
    width: 78px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

This is what's giving you the problem.
GL!

Comment: Thanks Guys, forgot about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your `style.css` file, you have `a:hover` set to a width of 78px. Get rid of that and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Looks like I was beat to the punch :)

Comment: Thanks Mate, your help was appreciated, the only reason I gave him best answer is because he posted beforehand :) Thanks to both.